# Collection view visible behind navigation bar in iMessage Extension in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessage-extension

I'm developing iMessage Extension app.
My problem is that the collection view is visible behind navigation bar in expand mode.

Is there anybody who has experience in this area?
Looking for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Give constraint to your `CollectionView` like this while `Constraint to margins`is unselected.

[image]

[Source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4mGZw4MNicDb0xMV2dIRDVYMUU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Of course, I gave constraints (top:0 left :0,,,) before. but that doesn't solve problem.

Comment: in given source code the collection view is not being under navigation bar, check that, make sure `Constraint to margins` is  **unselected**

Comment: can you please give test data to enable scroll and test again? if you scroll collection view, it will be even shown behind navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing the content offset of the collection view to in order to shift it below the navigation bar, something like this:

```
collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it only adjusts the scroll view start position, and it is still visible behind navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

After give Constraints(Top:0,Left:0,Right:0,Bottom:0),you should give Top   Constraints of CollectionView to Top Layout Guide.Bottom ratherthan Superview.Top like this:

**CollectionView.Top = Top Layout Guide.Bottom is set to 0.**